# Finnd shortest path in social Friend graph java

Tags: java, data-structures, graph, shortest-path

```
  **
```

***In this program, you will implement some useful algorithms for graphs that represent friendships (e.g. Facebook). A
friendship graph is an undirected graph without any weights on the edges. It is a simple graph because there are no
self loops (a self loop is an edge from a vertex to itself), or multiple edges (a multiple edge means more than edge
between a pair of vertices).

The vertices in the graphs for this assignment represent two kinds of people: students and non-students. Each vertex
will store the name of the person. If the person is a student, the name of the school will also be stored.
Here's a sample friendship graph:***

**

```
 public static ArrayList<String> shortestChain(Graph g, String p1, String p2) {

            /** COMPLETE THIS METHOD **/

            // FOLLOWING LINE IS A PLACEHOLDER TO MAKE COMPILER HAPPY
            // CHANGE AS REQUIRED FOR YOUR IMPLEMENTATION

            int indexP1=g.map.get(p1);
            int indexP2=g.map.get(p2);

            Person perSon1=g.members[indexP1];
            Person perSon2=g.members[indexP2];



            /*System.out.println("Edge Point ="+perSon1.first.next);
            System.out.println("Edge Point"+ perSon2.name+"="+perSon2.first.fnum);
            System.out.println("Edge Point"+ perSon2.name+"="+perSon2.first.next.fnum);
            System.out.println("Edge Point"+ perSon2.name+"="+perSon2.first.next.next.fnum);
            */
            int count =0;
            Friend ptr=perSon1.first;
            while(ptr!=null){
                //System.out.println("Next Element="+ptr.fnum);

                Person per=g.members[ptr.fnum];
                System.out.println("Connection Friend="+per.name);

                /*if(per.name.equalsIgnoreCase(perSon2.name)){
                    System.out.println("Found data-path="+perSon1.name+"--"+per.name);
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Not Single Edge path");
                }*/

                Queue<Person> queue=new Queue<>();
                queue.enqueue(per);

                ptr=ptr.next;

                count=count+1;
            }
            System.out.println("Total Connections="+count);

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Finds all cliques of students in a given school.
         * 
         * Returns an array list of array lists - each constituent array list contains
         * the names of all students in a clique.
         * 
         * @param g Graph for which cliques are to be found.
         * @param school Name of school
         * @return Array list of clique array lists. Null if there is no student in the
         *         given school
         */
        public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> cliques(Graph g, String school) {

            /** COMPLETE THIS METHOD **/

            // FOLLOWING LINE IS A PLACEHOLDER TO MAKE COMPILER HAPPY
            // CHANGE AS REQUIRED FOR YOUR IMPLEMENTATION
            return null;

        }

        /**
         * Finds and returns all connectors in the graph.
         * 
         * @param g Graph for which connectors needs to be found.
         * @return Names of all connectors. Null if there are no connectors.
         */
        public static ArrayList<String> connectors(Graph g) {

            /** COMPLETE THIS METHOD **/

            // FOLLOWING LINE IS A PLACEHOLDER TO MAKE COMPILER HAPPY
            // CHANGE AS REQUIRED FOR YOUR IMPLEMENTATION
            return null;

        }
    }
```

The current ouput i am getting here

```
graph ={ming=8, rich=13, michele=2, sergei=3, samir=6, heather=11, aparna=7, kaitlin=5, nick=9, tom=14, bob=10, rachel=12, ricardo=4, sam=0, jane=1}
Person Name=sam, isStudent=true,school=rutgers,first=1
Person Name=jane, isStudent=true,school=rutgers,first=5
Person Name=michele, isStudent=true,school=cornell,first=14
Person Name=sergei, isStudent=true,school=rutgers,first=7
Person Name=ricardo, isStudent=true,school=penn state,first=9
Person Name=kaitlin, isStudent=true,school=rutgers,first=9
Person Name=samir, isStudent=false,school=null,first=7
Person Name=aparna, isStudent=true,school=rutgers,first=4
Person Name=ming, isStudent=true,school=penn state,first=9
Person Name=nick, isStudent=true,school=penn state,first=11
Person Name=bob, isStudent=true,school=rutgers,first=6
Person Name=heather, isStudent=true,school=penn state,first=9
Person Name=rachel, isStudent=false,school=null,first=2
Person Name=rich, isStudent=true,school=ucla,first=14
Person Name=tom, isStudent=true,school=ucla,first=13
15
Edge Point =friends.Friend@5a42bbf4
Edge Point aparna=4
Edge Point aparna=6
Edge Point aparna=3
Connection Friend=heather
Not Single Edge path
Connection Friend=ming
Not Single Edge path
Connection Friend=ricardo
Not Single Edge path
Connection Friend=kaitlin
Not Single Edge path
Total Connections=4
```

Comment: And the question is ...? If your answer is "the results aren't correct" then: what do you expect, i.e. what would be correct results? Did you step through your code with a debugger?

Comment: so, shall we debug your code? or shall we implement your two missing methods now? and even worse, although you showed some output but not the original input aka graph...

Comment: If your question is how to find the shortest path between 2 nodes in the kind of graph the exercise describes...take a look at Dijkstra algorithm and implement it using the particular classes/structures available.

Comment: But in that you have some distance but you have no distance

Comment: you only can find by frnd of friends